# Rails, Alphanumeric validation in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I let users select a username, just like the twitter signup page: https://twitter.com/signup

When the user starts typing a username, I want in real-time to let the user know if the username is available & valid.

The regex I've been using to validate the username is alphanumeric is:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Given `params[:username]`

In the controller, how can I validate if the username is alphanumeric or not. Note, I'm not saving the record here just validation. so a model validation wouldn't work.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: The regexp should use \A and \z instead of ^ and $. (http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd still want to use model validations.

Something like this perhaps:

```
class User
  validates :username, :format => { :with => /your regex/ }, :uniqueness => true
end

# then in some controller action or rack app
def test_username
  user = User.new(:username => params[:username])

  # Call user.valid? to trigger the validations, then test to see if there are 
  # any on username, which is all you're concerned about here.
  #
  # If there are errors, they'd be returned so you can use them in the view,
  # if not, just return success or something.
  #
  if !user.valid? && user.errors[:username].any?     
    render :json => { :success => false, :errors => user.errors[:username] }
  else
    render :json => { :success => true }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. errors are always nil. Don't you need to actually save to get errors back?

Comment: Sorry, in the first iteration I left out the call to `user.valid?`, which is necessary.  I added it in an edit.

Comment: very nice. Thank you! Is there a way to get back just the first error?

Comment: sure, `user.errors[:username].first`.  Note that with the default translations the error wouldn't contain the attribute name, so it'd be like "is invalid" for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /^[a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+$/i

unless your_string.match(r).nil?
  # validation succeeded
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is a little overly verbose. I'd actually try the following regex for the alphanumeric validation:

```
/\A[A-Z0-9]+\z/i
```